# Turtlebot netbook: wireless network setup problem

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to this, so sorry if this is a basic question. I recently received a TurtleBot. It's already assembled and came with a Lonovo X130e netbook running Ubuntu 10.4 . I believe the TurtleBot software is already installed, but in the TurtleBot tutorials it is unclear if I still need to download something from the TurtleBot USB Drive, which also came with the robot? Either way, the main problem is that the netbook won't connect to the wireless network. I have tried Fn+F5. I have looked for a manual switch on the laptop. I've looked at what feels like hundreds of Ubuntu and TurtleBot forums and even called Lonovo support. This is a very basic problem and I can't figure it out. Please help!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39311/turtlebot-netbook:-wireless-network-setup-problem/) by [cmm386](https://answers.ros.org/users/2887/cmm386/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-07-19**:
You don't need to download anything from that USB drive; it's provided for system restore purposes. When you mean "won't connect", what does it do? Are no networks detected at all? Have you tried connecting to other wireless networks or decreasing the security on your network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a ROS question, but I have an idea as to how I could answer it. For future reference, post wireless driver questions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=336). But, I would recommend you try upgrading your Ubuntu system. I'm pretty sure you have a Realtek wireless card, which was first supported in 11.04. If you want to be persistent, check this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604101).

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0